# Spring integration 'Dispatcher has no subscribers' when channels are used in init-method

Tags: spring-integration

Getting 'Dispatcher has no subscribers' error while trying to post message to a channel in spring bean's init-method. Please take a look at below example:

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:rmi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/rmi"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/rmi
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/rmi/spring-integration-rmi.xsd">

    <bean id="currencyService" class="com.demo.CurrencyService" init-method="init"/>

    <int:channel id="currencyChannel" />
    <int:channel id="currencyReplyChannel">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>
    <rmi:outbound-gateway id="currencyServiceGateway"
        request-channel="currencyChannel" remote-channel="currencyServiceChannel"
        reply-channel="currencyReplyChannel" host="localhost" port="2197" />
</beans>
```

Spring managed bean:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.integration.Message;
import org.springframework.integration.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.integration.core.PollableChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage;

public class CurrencyService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel currencyChannel;

    @Autowired
    private PollableChannel currencyReplyChannel;

    private CurrencyListBO currencyListBO;

    public CurrencyListBO getCurrencyList() {
        return currencyListBO;
    }

    public void init() {
        CurrencyIN request = new CurrencyIN();
        request.setChannelCode("RMW");
        request.setTransactionType(CurrencyIN.TransactionType.currencyLoaderService
                .toString());
        GenericMessage<IRequestBO> message = new GenericMessage<IRequestBO>(
                request);
        MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();
        template.send(currencyChannel, message);
        Message<CurrencyListBO> reply = template.receive(currencyReplyChannel);
        currencyListBO = reply.getPayload();
    }
}
```

If instead of init-method, currencyListBO was initialized after during first call, everything works fine.

```
public CurrencyListBO getCurrencyList() {
    if(currencyListBO == null) {
        init();
    }
    return currencyListBO;
}
```

Please let me know what is the issue with first approach.

Comment: Same issue even if '@PostConstruct' is used instead of 'init-method'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The init/@PostConstruct method is called after your bean has been instantiated but before the rest of the context has been wired up (in this case before the RMI adapter has been subscribed to the channel).

You need to wait until the context is fully refreshed.

One way to do that is implement

```
ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
```

and put your code in

```
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)
```

That method will be called after the context is fully wired.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. This approach worked. But I had to write a technical service that implements ApplicationListener and initiate all required business services.  If I try to implement ApplicationListener on business service itself, I am unable to inject this business service as a dependency for my unit tests.  Seems that this behavior is correct and clean (to have one init service rather than implementing ApplicationListener interface on all required business interfaces) but would like to check whether this is intended or again an error I am facing.

Comment: That is a reasonable approach; it's best to minimize framework dependencies where possible. Of course, you can simulate the event in your unit tests. Or, of course, you can use the technique of running the init code on first use rather than in an init method. Yet another technique would be to implement SmartLifeCycle; set the phase to Integer.MAX_VALUE and your bean's start() method will be one of the last to be called (if isAutoStartup() returns true).